# How to move an AWS subnet into a different availability zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

I created two subnets without any preference of the availability zone(AZ). So, now I have two subnets in one AZ. I know that I can extend the VPC and create new subnets but I simply want to move a subnet into a different zone. Is there any way I can move a subnet to a different AZ on AWS?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not possible.

An Availability Zone is nominated when the Subnet is created. It is not possible to change the AZ on a Subnet.

You should either create another subnet, or delete the subnet and recreate it in a different AZ.

Comment: If you delete and recreate it inthe new AZ, can you recreate it with the same CIDR range that the deleted one?

Comment: @рüффп Yes, once a subnet is deleted, the CIDR can be used for another subnet. Of course, all resources must be deleted from the subnet before the subnet itself can be deleted.